# App crashes when I use jniSvmTrain

Tags: android, libsvm

When I run `jniSvmTrain(svmTrainOptions + dataTrainPath + modelPath);`, the app crashes and I can't figure out why (it works well when this line is deleted). The purpose is to build an app based on AndroidLibSVM to train it on the iris dataset. I integrate AndroidLibSVM in Android Studio by following the instructions here : https://github.com/yctung/AndroidLibSvm.

I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://www.decom.ufop.br/imobilis/tutorial-android-implementacao-svm-multiclass/) on AndroidLibSVM.

This is the code for **IrisActivity.java** file :

```java
package example.iris;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class IrisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button go;

    String appFolderPath;
    String systemPath;

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("jnilibsvm");
    }

    private native void jniSvmTrain(String cmd);
    private native void jniSvmPredict(String cmd);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_iris);

        go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);

        systemPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        appFolderPath = systemPath + "libsvm/";

        // iris.train is available here : https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass/iris.scale
        final String dataTrainPath = appFolderPath + "iris.train ";
        final String dataPredictPath = appFolderPath + "iris.predict ";
        final String modelPath = appFolderPath + "iris.model ";
        final String outputPath = appFolderPath + "iris.output ";

        final String svmTrainOptions = "-s 0 -t 2 -g 1 -r 0 ";

        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // The next line conducts the app to crash, but why ?
                jniSvmTrain(svmTrainOptions + dataTrainPath + modelPath);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Than you for your help.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: The line `jniSvmTrain(svmTrainOptions + dataTrainPath + modelPath);` conducts the app to crash (yet the APK file is generated and installed by Android Studio). When it is deleted, the app works well.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run jniSvmTrain(svmTrainOptions + dataTrainPath + modelPath);,
>   the app crashes

You should put the `button` go below the `setContentView`

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_iris);
 go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you suggest but the app still crashes because of the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the logcat I found the problem :

```
03-09 02:34:04.252 27921-27921/example.iris D/AndroidLibSvmNDK: NDK: jniSvmTrain cmd = -s 0 -t 2 -g 1 -r 0 /storage/emulated/0/libsvm/iris.train /storage/emulated/0/libsvm/iris.model
03-09 02:34:04.256 27921-27921/example.iris D/AndroidLibSvmNDK: NDK: can't open input file /storage/emulated/0/libsvm/iris.train
```

Solution : the app crashes because I forgot to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to the **AndroidManifest.xml** file to get the right to access to the internal memory.